# Index the content within an iframe

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, iframe

We have created an web application that gives the client the possibility to use his websites as an online showroom (cars, bikes, etc etc).

What is offered is photo's, information about the vehicles and so on.

However, we would like to offer this as an iframe rather then developing plugins for certain CMS systems (Drupal, WordPress etc etc) or giving an file_get_contents/curl method.

The only downside we can think of is that the content within the iframe isn't going to be indexed by Google.

Is it possible to let it be indexed to the parent webpage? So that the content of the iframe belongs to Domain A.

We've tried it with canonical tags but this didn't work.

Any ideas or is this just not possible?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEO: If another website uses a iframe from our website, would the links in the iframe appear to be coming from our website or from theirs?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67654/seo-if-another-website-uses-a-iframe-from-our-website-would-the-links-in-the-i)

Comment: "the content within the iframe isn't going to be indexed by Google" - It's not that the content in the iframe is not going to be indexed, on the contrary, the content in the iframe can be indexed. It's just that it may not be indexed within the context of the parent document. It will be indexed under its own merits and can consequently be returned on its own in the SERPs.

Comment: @w3dk If this is not marked as a duplicate, it sounds like you have the perfect answer. Cheers!!

Comment: While the answer to [google - SEO: If another website uses a iframe from our website, would the links in the iframe appear to be coming from our website or from theirs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67654/seo-if-another-website-uses-a-iframe-from-our-website-would-the-links-in-the-i) appears applicable to this question, that question is asking about links while this one is asking about content.   They are therefore not duplicate to me.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for client:**
If the client want to get seo benefit out of this, then they can call this url from their backend and render it using a headless browser like prerender and include that as a html on page. So that crawler can see that content and index it.

https://prerender.io/

**Solution from you - the provider**
Other way around, you should add this capability in your system, to be a complete solution for your clients.

Create a rest api that client can call and get the html, rather than the using html url in iframe.
So this will add flexibility to your application and make your clients happy.

**Your api can be :**

http://www.example.com/getSiteContent?clientid=xxx&mode=(html/iframe)

In mode html : you can return the complete page html as a string (the current content in your iframe url as html string that client can include in page from backend)
In mode iframe : return what you are returning currently

Answer (score 2):

### Robots `indexifembedded`

On January 21, 2022 Google [introduced this new robots tag](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/01/robots-meta-tag-indexifembedded). The tag most notably affects media sites that would like to have their content indexed when it's embedded on third-party pages.

The tag will work nicely in this situation.

**Example usage:**

```html
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="indexifembedded" />
<!-- OR -->
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,indexifembedded" />
```

It should be placed on internal pages that house the content that will be embedded elsewhere. When accompanied with `noindex`, `indexifembedded` tells Google that it can can embed the content hosted on a page during indexing.

So you might have:

**URL:**

```
https://yoursite.com/app/media/embed/
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,indexifembedded" />
    <title>Media Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Important to note is that it *must* appear with `noindex`. So you cannot say:

```html
<meta name="googlebot" content="index,indexifembedded" />
```

Comment: That is interesting.  Sounds like it means "index ONLY if embedded and not on its own"

Comment: Exactly, that is how I've interpreted it as well. However, I'm curious...I bet a self referencing canonical throws it for a loop.

Comment: Interesting, but I hope Google thought of that and made sure it works even with a self canonical.