# Will a self hosted video get indexed on Google Video Search if I use an iframe?

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index, video, iframe

We created a hosting domain for the videos, and embedded them on our website using iframes. Will that stand in the way of the Google crawler indexing our videos in Google Video Search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the minimum requirements for Google to be able to Crawl your video:

> **Minimum requirements for a video search result:**
>
> If you want your video to be eligible for search results:
>
> - **Google must be able to find the video.** Videos are identified in the page by the presence of an HTML tag, for example: `<video>`,
>   `<embed>`, or `<object>`. Ensure that the page doesn't [require
>   complex user actions or specific URL fragments to
>   load,](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156442?hl=en#complex-javascript)
>   or Google might not find it. **Tip:** Although we can find videos
>   embedded in a page through natural crawling, you can help us find your
>   videos by posting a [video
>   sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80471).
> - **You must [provide a high-quality thumbnail image for the video.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156442?hl=en#thumbnails)**
> - **Make sure that each video lives in a publicly available page** where users can watch the video. The page should not be require a
>   login by the user. The page should also not be blocked by
>   [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608) or
>   [noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710) (it must
>   be accessible by Google).
> - **The video content should apply specifically to the content of its host page.** For example, if you have a recipe page for peach pie,
>   don't embed a video about pastries in general.
> - Ensure that any information you provide in a video sitemap or video markup is **consistent** with the actual video content.

And for better results, you shall follow the maximum rules provided on their Answer: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156442?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

gael offers good advice. In addition to that, on the hosting domain, apply the new `indexifembedded` meta robots directive.

This will ensure that your content can be fully crawled and indexed if you're using iframes.

See [this answer about indexifembedded](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/138485/122139) for more information.